# Modify JDBC code to target multiple database servers for Inesrt/Update/Deletions

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Is there a way that I can use JDBC to target multiple databases when I execute statements (basic inserts, updates, deletes).

For example, assume both servers [200.200.200.1] and [200.200.200.2] have a database  named `MyDatabase`, and the databases are exactly the same.  I'd like to run `"INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(1, 2)"` on both databases at the same time.

**Note regarding JTA/XA:**

We're developing a JTA/XA architecture to target multiple databases in the same transaction, but it won't be ready for some time.  I'd like to use standard JDBC batch commands and have them hit multiple servers for now if its possible.  I realize that it won't be transaction safe, I just wan't the commands to hit both servers for basic testing at the moment.

Comment: It is very bad coding style to not list the columns in the insert statement.

Comment: Agreed, I was just being lazy for a quick example.  Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one connection per database.  Once you have those, the standard auto commit/rollback calls will work.

You could try Spring; it already has transaction managers set up.

Even if you don't use Spring, all you have to do is get XA versions of the JDBC driver JARs in your CLASSPATH.  Two phase commit will not work if you don't have them.

I'd wonder if replication using the database would not be a better idea.  Why should the middle tier care about database clustering?

Comment: Thank you for the help :) Our XA code makes use of those drivers and Spring (though I don't know Spring well, I'm not the one writing it), we're seeing some funny behavior though so we're investigating before use.  We're using VectorWise and it doesn't support replication - we do use replication for the SQL Server version of the product though and it works great.

Comment: Just to be clear... you're saying I'll need to create 2 connections, 2 prepared statements, and call executeBatch(), etc, on each one individually right?  Or is there a trick to link the connections and let JDBC manage them together?

Comment: The first one: two connections, two statements.  Batch is your choice; you can execute with two roundtrips within transaction scope if you want.  I don't know of any tricks to help.  I also don't know what "funny behavior" means or how you're writing Spring.   That's a larger issue.  I will say that Spring XA works great, with multiple databases and even database/queue.

Answer (score 1):

Best quick and dirty way for development is to use multiple database connections. They won't be in the same transaction since they are in different connection. I don't think this would be much of an issue if this is just for testing.

When your JTA/XA architecture is ready, just plug it into the already working code.